# Замена значений атрибута value тега input

Tags: javascript, html, input

разбираюсь с api интернет-эквайринга, для успешной отправки формы необходимо передать параметр receipt, у которого есть ряд обязательных значений.
Выглядит он подобным образом:

```
<input class="PayRow" type="hidden" name="receipt" value='{"Email": "test@test.ru","Items": [ {"Name": "Наименование товара 1","Price":10000,"Quantity": 1.00,"Amount": 10000 }]}'>
```

Значения Email и Items являются обязательными, при этом у Items обязательны Name, Price и Amount.

`Email` клиента я получаю в поле ввода перед оплатой, в другом поле вычисляется `Amount`, то есть эти два значения у меня есть. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста - как можно заменить `"test@test.ru"` на e-mail клиента, а также в `"Price":10000` и `"Amount": 10000`цифры на значение Amount (Price и Amount всегда будут равны, так как Quantity будет 1) автоматически на те, что у меня имеются.

```
Amount : <input class="PayRow" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="paySum" id="priceId">

Email : <input class="PayRow" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="payEmail">
```

Comment: очень сложно. может сформировать объект и уже потом отправить его  через post запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего в момент отправки формировать содержимое value, подставляя в нужные места значения полей:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  let receipt = '{"Email": "'+$('#email').val()+'", "Items": [{"Name": "Наименование товара 1","Price": '+Number($('#priceId').val())+',"Quantity": 1.00,"Amount": '+Number($('#priceId').val())+'}]}';
  
  $('[name="receipt"]').val(receipt);
  
  console.log($('[name="receipt"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount : <input class="PayRow" type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="paySum" id="priceId"><br /><br />

Email : <input class="PayRow" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="payEmail" id="email"><br /><br />

<input class="PayRow" type="hidden" name="receipt" value="">
<button>Отправить</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, а если в button уже вызывается другая функция onclick, которая отправляет форму на сервер, то какая будет последовательность событий? Замена receipt -> затем отправка с новым receipt или наоборот?

Comment: @IlyaPolivin, сначала, разумеется, формирование value, а затем уже отправка

Comment: @IlyaPolivin, и если Вам помог ответ, примите его, поставив галочку )

Comment: надеюсь помог (галочку поставил =) ), я пока не очень силен в js и какой-то локальный тест провести у меня знаний не хватает, а "живой" тест пока провести не могу по другим причинам :D

Comment: к сожалению не срабатывает, выдается ошибка "Извините, произошла ошибка при регистрации заказа. Ошибка: 1 Параметры не сопоставлены." Видимо отправка происходит до подстановки значения. Если Вам не сложно, можете посмотреть весь код [ссылка](https://codepen.io/nomelnomel/pen/XygwRv)

Comment: @IlyaPolivin, естественно, не срабатывает: Вы просто скопировали мой пример и даже не подключили библиотеку jQuery (а без неё ничего работать не будет). Кроме того, там у Вас были ещё ошибки в коде. Я, вроде, поправил - вот рабочий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/p35vjybk/2/ Только учтите, что курс евро я там прописал фиксированный - 75 рублей (потому что php-парсер, который якобы должен динамически подгружать курс, в песочнице не работает).

Answer (score 0):

```
const receipt = {
        "Email": document.getElementById('mail').value,
        "Items": [{ 
            "Name": document.getElementById('name').value,
            "Price":10000,
            "Quantity": 1.00,
            "Amount": 10000 
        }]
    }

    var saveData = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someaction.do/controller/action",
        data: JSON.stringify(receipt),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resultData){
            alert("Save Complete");
        }
    });
```